# iPad simulator on 13'' screen

Tags: ipad

Quick question to anyone who has downloaded iPhone OS 3.2 beta.

Does the iPad simulator fit well on a 1280x800 screen?

I was planning to get a MB Air pretty soon.

Comment: An iPad has a resolution of 1024x786, so if you put your Dock on the side of your screen you should be okay to see the whole screen.

Comment: This is funny, I was just thinking that they'll probably kill the macbook air, because it's too similar to the iPad.

Comment: The screen resolution is 1024x768. But what about the 1 inch thick bezel on each side? That's what I am concerned about.

Comment: This is a programming related question (an iphone simulator is explicitly for developers) so the reason for close is probably misleading. I suspect the real issue is that the NDA prohibits discussion of SDK features but thats not available as a close option?

Comment: The iPhone simulator is a tool specifically for programming. How could this possibly NOT be programming related?

Comment: @KennyWinker yeah but you can do anything on an Air.